# Jquery Jcarousel not working with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jcarousel

I have this code:

```
<div class="modal hide" style="display:none" id='mostrarImagenes'>
    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#009975">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="background:#9FD5D1;">

        <p id="galeriaImagenes">
            <a href="../imagenes/img1.jpg" target="_self" class="inline-block litebox" data-litebox-group="group-1"><img src="../imagenes/img1.jpg" class="inline-block" width="100" height="100"/></a>
            <a href="../imagenes/img2.jpg" target="_self" class="inline-block litebox" data-litebox-group="group-1"><img src="../imagenes/img2.jpg" class="inline-block" width="100" height="100"/></a>
            <a href="../imagenes/img3.jpg" target="_self" class="inline-block litebox" data-litebox-group="group-1"><img src="../imagenes/img3.jpg" class="inline-block" width="100" height="100"/></a>
            <a href="../imagenes/img4.jpg" target="_self" class="inline-block litebox" data-litebox-group="group-1"><img src="../imagenes/img4.jpg" class="inline-block" width="100" height="100"/></a>
            <a href="../imagenes/img5.jpg" target="_self" class="inline-block litebox" data-litebox-group="group-1"><img src="../imagenes/img5.jpg" class="inline-block" width="100" height="100"/></a>
            <a href="../imagenes/img6.png" target="_self" class="inline-block litebox" data-litebox-group="group-1"><img src="../imagenes/img6.png" class="inline-block" width="100" height="100"/></a>
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Which is inside an HTML document. When I click on any of the images, then the Jcarousel shows up correctly, like this:

[image]

The problem is that this gallery needs to be filled from a database, and I've achieved this with this code:

```
<?php
    include("FuncionesBaseDatos.php");
    $bd = new FuncionesBaseDatos();

    $idVisita = $_POST['t1'];

    $queryImagenes = pg_query("
        SELECT
            ID_IMAGEN,
            NOMBRE,
            RUTA
        FROM IMAGEN
        WHERE ID_VISITA = $idVisita
    ");

    while($imagen = pg_fetch_row($queryImagenes)){
        $aux = str_replace('\\', '/',$imagen[2]) . '/' . $imagen[1];
        echo "
            <a id='$imagen[0]' href='$aux' target='_self' class='inline-block litebox' data-litebox-group='group-1'>
                <img src='$aux' class='inline-block' width='100' height='100' alt='$imagen[1]'/>
            </a>
        ";
    }
?>
```

But, despite of this, when I click on these new images, Jcarousel does not show up, instead of that, the image is opened by the browser, like this:

[image]

And I don't have a clue of why this is happening.

Any ideas will be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The PHP should have nothing to do with the jQuery save for how PHP outputs your HTML. What is the output of the PHP? Does that output look like your first example?

Comment: How is jquery linked in the html? If is inside the header then jcarousel is initialized before the html generated by php is injected in the page so it doesnt find anything and you get no carousel but just plain html.

Comment: @Bolza, jquery is linked exactly inside the HTML head tags, so how can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, the output is in second code box in the question...

Comment: That is not output, that is the PHP code. What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand you... I know it's PHP code, but in the second line of the while loop there's the echo with the HTML code I'm outputting... Is not that what you're asking for?